# SQL view query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-view

These are my tables:

```
portal_users(id, first_name, last_name, email, ...,)
courses(id, name, location, capacity, ...,)
feedback_questions(id, question, ...,)
feedback_answers(id, answers, IDquestion, IDuser, IDcourse)
```

I want to do a view with this:

```
course | first_name | last_name | IDuser | IDcourse | question_1 | answer_1 | question_2 | answer_2
```

So far

```
CREATE VIEW feedback_answers_vw
as 
SELECT 
fa.id,
fa.answer,
fq.question,
pu.first_name,
pu.last_name,
    fa.IDuser,
fa.IDcourse
FROM    feedback_answers fa
INNER JOIN feedback_questions fq
    ON fa.IDquestion = fq.id
INNER JOIN portal_users pu
    ON fa.IDuser = pu.id
INNER JOIN courses cu
    on fa.IDcourse = cu.id
 GROUP BY
fa.IDcourse, fa.IDuser
```

This just display one question and its answers, but not all the questions that belong to the same course and user.

I could hardcode this with something like this in the SELECT statement

```
SELECT 
    fa.id,
    (select question
        from feedback_questions
        where id = 1) as question_1,
    (select question
        from feedback_questions
        where id = 2) as question_2,
    (select question
        from feedback_questions
        where id = 3) as question_3,
    pu.first_name,
    pu.last_name,
    fa.IDuser,
    fa.IDcourse
```

But I want to do it in the right way, so I won't be changing the code everytime that a question is added.

**Edit:**
This is data example of my tables:

```
**Portal users:**
1, tom, hanks, tom_hanks@example.com, ..., 
2, steven, spielberg, steven@example.com, ...,


**Courses:**
1, quality, california, 30
2, information technologies, texas, 24


**Questions:**
1, How did you find the course?, ...,
2, Do you want purchase order?, ...,


**Answers:**
1, Internet, 1, 1, 1
2, yes, 2, 1, 1
3, TV, 1, 2, 1,
4, no, 2, 2, 1,
5, Internet, 1, 1, 2
6, yes, 1, 1, 2
```

**This are data example I want to display in the view:**

```
course|first_name|last_name|IDuser|IDcourse|Question_1|Answer_1|Question_2|Answer_2

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
quality | tom | hanks | 1 | 1 | How did you find the course? | Internet | Do you want purchase order? | yes

quality | steven | spielberg | 2 | 1 | How did you find the course? | TV |   Do you want purchase order? | no

Information technologies | tom | hanks | 1 | 2 How did you find the course? | Internet | Do you want purchase order? | yes
```

Answer (score 0):

After some sample data was posted, it is clear a pivot table (in access/excel known as a 'crosstab') is needed here. We could hard code a select with some case statements to cover a fixed number of questions, but that solution would have to be revisited each time a question was added or removed. @drapp has such a solution below.

However, what we really want is the number of columns returned by the view to grow and shrink with the number of questions. Unfortunately mysql doesn't have any built in functions to help us build one. The best solution I found online is http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=523. The author proposes building the sql select statement dynamically then executing it. It is actually a pretty elegant solution.

Faced with this requirement, I wouldn't do this work in SQL. The problem I foresee is that as the numbers of questions rises, more and more columns will be returned; your view would quickly slow down to a crawl, and eventually stop working altogether. I would try to transform the data outside of sql, perhaps in an etl tool, application server, or BI tool.

Or, if I had the ability to (and I never do), I would switch database engines. Here are three solutions from other engines that provide tools for creating pivot tables:

- Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html
- Postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html
- SQL Server: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Comment: Display the number of users that answered the questions * number of questions.

I.E.
If I have 3 questions and 2 users answered. Display 6 Rows. 

3 rows per user, the difference between the rows are the question and the answer

Comment: Let me make sure I understand, you want a list of questions and answers to get displayed as in the same row with columns for each question answer pair?

Comment: Maybe if you post some sample data and your expected result it would help. It is sounding more and more like you want to pivot the table.

Comment: Thank you, I just edit the question with data example

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you would actually need it as a view, and here is a sample query for it.

If you look at the first part of the where clause, it is based on a minimum of question ID = 1.  I then join that to the course table and portal_user table to get those fields.  Since the feedback answers is the first table, we can immediately get that answer, but also join to the questions table to get the question.

So now, how to simply expand this query for future questions?  Notice the LEFT-JOINs right after that for the feedback answers AGAIN, but this time as an alias "fa2" (feedback_answers2), and the JOIN clause is based on the same user, same course, but only for question ID = 2.  This then joins to the questions table on the fa2.questionID to the questions table (alias fq2).  And then another exact same setup but for question 3.  So here, I am doing nothing but using the same tables, but just different aliases.  They all start with question 1, and if there is a question 2, get it... if a question 3, get it too, expand as needed, no group by, etc.

So now if you only cared about a single course you were interested, just add that to the outermost WHERE clause, nothing else needs to change.  Get 10 questions, copy/paste the LEFT-JOIN components for the corresponding question IDs.

```
SELECT
      c.name as course,
      pu.first_name,
      pu.last_name,
      fa1.IDUser,
      fa1.IDCourse,
      fq1.question as question1,
      fa1.answers as answer1,
      fq2.question as question2,
      fa2.answers as answer2,
      fq3.question as question3,
      fa3.answers as answer3
   from
      feedback_answers fa1
         JOIN courses c
            ON fa1.IDCourse = c.id
         JOIN portal_users pu
            ON fa1.IDUser = pu.id
         JOIN feedback_questions fq1
            ON fa1.IDquestion = fq1.id

         LEFT JOIN feedback_answers fa2
            ON fa1.IDUser = fa2.IDUser
            AND fa1.IDCourse = fa2.IDCourse
            AND fa2.id = 2
            LEFT JOIN feedback_questions fq2
               ON fa2.IDquestion = fq2.id

         LEFT JOIN feedback_answers fa3
            ON fa1.IDUser = fa3.IDUser
            AND fa1.IDCourse = fa3.IDCourse
            AND fa2.id = 3
            LEFT JOIN feedback_questions fq3
               ON fa3.IDquestion = fq3.id

   where
      fa1.id = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

We just talked about views in my DB Design class and my Professor said that you can't use a join in a VIEW statement. I can't recall why not but your issues looks familiar.

Comment: This is false, what would be the purpose of a view without any sort of join?

Comment: I will ask tomorrow in class.